# Does introducing a gauge field into the complex scalar field theory Lagrangian change its dynamics?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I've been reading Lancaster & Blundell, and in Chapter 14 they focus on the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}=(\partial^\mu\psi)^\dagger(\partial_\mu\psi) - m^2\psi^\dagger\psi.
$$
To impose invariance to the transformation $\psi\rightarrow\psi\exp(i\alpha(x))$, where $\alpha(x)$ is a coordinate-dependent phase, they replace the derivatives in $\mathcal{L}$ with covariant derivatives
$$
D_\mu = \partial_\mu + iqA_\mu.
$$
Invariance  then follows if we also admit the transformation
$$
A_\mu\rightarrow A_\mu-\frac{1}{q}\partial_\mu\alpha(x).
$$

Now, my question is a simple one: why are we 'allowed' to change the Lagrangian seemingly arbitrarily? I see how this change leads to the invariance of $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to the transformation $\psi\rightarrow\psi\exp(i\alpha(x))$, but surely in doing so we change the dynamics of the field $\psi$? Expansion of the `new' Lagrangian would seem to suggest that the EL equations do indeed result in different dynamics.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I always didn't like how textbooks explained this... it's not that you're "allowed" to do this or that. Your first Lagrangian represents one theory, adding a gauge field represents a completely different theory. The motivation is that the change is relatively simple, not that the change does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed true and is what is called the gauge principle. It tells us that if we make a global symmetry local, we need to add a corresponding gauge field such that the total Lagrangian still remains invariant under this local gauge transformation. This is a new dynamical field which has its own equations of motion and can couple to the fermion leading to interactions.

In this case the original Lagrangian is invariant under $U(1)$ as $\psi \to \psi e^{i \alpha}$, note that also $\partial_\mu \psi \to \partial_\mu \psi e^{i \alpha}$. We say that these fields transform in the fundamental representation of $U(1)$.

Now after making our transformation local: $\alpha \equiv \alpha(x)$ it's easy to see that $\partial_\mu \psi \not\to  \partial_\mu \psi e^{i \alpha(x)}$
To account for this as we still want our field to transform in the fundamental representation we have to introduce a gauge field $A_\mu(x)$ and a covariant derivative $\mathcal{D}_\mu$ such that $\mathcal{D}_\mu \psi \to \mathcal{D}_\mu \psi e^{i\alpha(x)}$. This last transformation dictates how $A_\mu(x)$ should transform.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the physics convention, when you say $\mathcal D_\mu \psi e^{i\alpha(x)}$, do you mean $(\mathcal D_\mu \psi) e^{i\alpha(x)}$ or $\mathcal D_\mu (\psi e^{i\alpha(x)})$?

Comment: The second one, $\mathcal{D}_\mu$ acting on everything on the right if there are no brackets.

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned in some of the comments, the Lagrangians
$$
\mathcal{L}=(\partial^\mu\psi)^\dagger(\partial_\mu\psi)-m^2\psi^\dagger\psi
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{L}=(D^\mu\psi)^\dagger(D_\mu\psi)-m^2\psi^\dagger\psi+\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
$$
represent distinct theories each with their own properties.

The usual way to motivate the transition from the "ungauged" theory and the "gauged" one is to note that *if* we want invariance under the transformation $\psi\rightarrow e^{i\alpha}\psi$ for $\alpha=\alpha(x)$ an arbitrary real function, then taking a Lagrangian that's already invariant in the special case where $\alpha$ is a constant and replacing all the derivatives of $\psi$ by covariant derivatives $D_\mu$, would be good enough to construct a Lagrangian which is also invariant under the local transformations.

There is another way of looking at things, however, which may feel a little less ad hoc. Though this viewpoint can be described in terms of this example of $\psi$ fields, it's slightly more natural to start with the example of a vector field.

So, suppose that $V^a$ are the components of some vector field - note that these are only the components. The vector field itself, meaning the abstract object which is invariant under coordinate changes is $V=V^a\boldsymbol{e}_a$ where the $\boldsymbol{e}_a$ form a basis of vectors at each point in space (technically called frame fields). For example, in two dimensions, we could take $\boldsymbol{e}_0=\boldsymbol{\hat r}$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_1=\boldsymbol{\hat \theta}$.

Now the key assumption is that the physics of our system should not depend on the basis vectors we choose to represent our vector fields in - that is, if we changed to Cartesian unit vectors instead of polar unit vectors, the components $V^a$ would certainly need to change, but the object $V=V^a\boldsymbol{e}_a$ should not.

Since any change in the basis vectors $\boldsymbol{e}_a$ will be a (linear) map from a linear space to itself, these can be represented by matrices $U^a_b$ so under a change in basis we would have $\boldsymbol{e}^\prime_a=U^b_a\boldsymbol{e}_b$. If we are truly to be independent of the basis vectors, we will be able to perform such a transformation point by point, these basis change matrices may have arbitrary dependence on the spacetime point, $U^a_b=U^a_b(x)$. In order for $V$ to be independent of these changes, the components must transform by the inverse of $U$, $V^{\prime\,a}=U^{-1\, a}_b V^b$.

Finally now, we want to build our Lagrangian out of $V$ and its derivatives. So long as our manifold has a metric, we can build arbitrarily high derivatives out of the differential $d$ and the Hodge dual $*$. If we compute the differential of $V$ in terms of the components, we would find
$$
dV=(dV^a)\boldsymbol{e}_b+V^a(d\boldsymbol{e}_b).
$$
The differential of the components is simple because these are all $0$-forms (scalars), and so $d V^a=\partial_\nu V^adx^\nu$. For the differential of the basis vectors, we can first note that the result must

a) be a 1-form

b) be some combination of unit vectors again.

These two statements together imply the differential must take the generic form
$$
d\boldsymbol{e}_a=(A_\mu)_a^b\boldsymbol{e}_bdx^\mu
$$
where $A_{\mu\,b}^a$ is some unknown function, suggestively named. Putting this result back into the calculation of $dV$, we find
$$
dV=\partial_\mu V^a\boldsymbol{e}_adx^\mu+V^aA_{\mu\,a}^b\boldsymbol{e}_bdx^\mu.
$$
Collecting the differentials, unit vectors, and components together, this becomes
$$
dV=\boldsymbol{e}_adx^\mu(\delta^a_b\partial_\mu+A_{\mu\,b}^a)V^b=\boldsymbol{e}_adx^\mu(D_\mu)^a_bV^b.
$$
In the last line we have identified the covariant derivative $D$. This differs slightly from the covariant derivative in the question by overall scalings of $A$ (the $iq$) which could have been absorbed into our definition of $A$.

This expression also differs slightly from what's in the question by the additional indices $a$ and $b$ floating around. In the case of the complex scalar field, we are not dealing with a vector, but instead some object $\tilde \psi=\psi z$ where now $z$ is some complex number with $|z|=1$. This now plays the role our $\boldsymbol{e}$'s played before (but has no indices).

Since $z$ must have modulus 1, we can only transform to a new $z$ by $z^\prime=e^{iq\alpha}z$ where $\alpha=\alpha(x)$ in the same way the change of basis matrix $U$ was allowed to vary point to point (and $q$ has been put in for convenience). Since there are no indices on this $z$, our calculation of the differential would yield
$$
d\tilde \psi=dx^\mu zD_\mu\psi=dx^\mu z(\partial_\mu+iqA_\mu)\psi.
$$

As a fun side note, observe that if in the example of a vector we renamed $A$ to $\Gamma$ and called the gauge potential a Christoffel symbol instead, we would immediately reproduce the covariant derivative from general relativity.

Comment: You have given an idea of how we can geometrically approach gauge theory. However, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @NDewolf The question asked had two parts, first whether this Lagrangian is the same, and second why we should be 'allowed' to make this change. I started by answering that the Lagrangian are indeed different which answers the first question. The second part of the question is why such a change is reasonable. My answer is constructed to address this from a geometrical perspective.

Comment: The question was specifically related to how this is "allowed" with respect to the dynamics. Your answer is just a geometric way of phrasing invariance.